# Python: GET only 'value' from 'input' HTML (Mechanize + BeautifulSoup)

Tags: python, html, get, beautifulsoup, mechanize

I'm recently working with Python Mechanize & BeautifulSoup and I learned how to click and follow a link. 
I now want to GET a value from an HTML input and I'm very close to it but my code is **horrible!**
What I want to `print` is just

`9574363984643591128220162336881714997023153074560071601385105141859609`

from:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
<input size="100" name="query" value="95743639846435911282201623368817149970231530745600716013851051418596093791193" type="text">
```

My code is:

```
<!-- language: lang-py -->

response3 = br.follow_link(nr=11)           # follow the link
soup = BeautifulSoup(response3, "lxml")     # read the page
for n in soup.findAll('input'):             # find all <input >
    print n['value']                        # print the "value" of all <input >
```

My code is now printing **all** the `<input>` of the whole page!

But I just want to print the **first** `<input>` or the input with `name="query"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find it via the `name` attribute.

```
soup.find("input", attrs={"name":"query"})["value"]
```